# Segmentation error when calling a function

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, recursion

I have this recursive function which creates all possible strings from a dictionary and encrypt them so that they can be compared with some saved hashes.

Earlier, I had some predefined value for the max length of passwords but I tried to change it with `argv[1]`.
But when I execute my program, I get a `Segmentation Fault` with not explanation.

By the way, all the includes are present as they should but I didn't put them in the post since it is somewhat bugged.

```
int recur(char * mot , char * tab,int l,int max_l)
{

// Because this was an exercice we had to do in class , i deleted this part 
// so some of my classmates dont copy/paste my code
// if you are interested , contact me

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    char letters[36] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
    char s[10]="";
    s[9]='\0';
    int l=0;
    int max_l;
    sscanf (argv[1],"%d",&max_l);
    printf("max_l  :  %i\n",max_l);
    printf("Debut !  \n");
    recur(s,letters,l,max_l);
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You have plenty of problems in your code. One of them is that there are execution paths in the `recur` function where you don't return anything.

Comment: Piece of Advice. First thing to do when you get segmentation fault is to Debug your code with a debugger, and if you don't have one or don't know how to use it, then print out the values of variables at different positions to know what changes are made and where the program stops

Comment: Compile your code with all warnings & debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Improve the code to get no warnings. Use the debugger `gdb`

Comment: Thx for all your advices , i'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
printf("Argv[1] :  %s\n", max_l);
```

This is undefined behavior. You are giving wrong format specifier. That's why you get seg fault you are trying to print an `int` using `%s` format specifer. It looks for the `\0` and then it doesn't. So it accesses some memory which it shouldn't resulting in UB. (And that resulted in segmentation error).

It should be

```
 printf("Argv[1] :  %d\n", max_l);
```

Also another major problem is not every control flow of this recursive function returns `int`. This is a pathway to bigger problem. In case the there is no return value when one is expected the behavior will be undefined.

Comment: Thank you, it was the problem , i'll mark it as answer in 8 min